# Call one constructor from another

Tags: c#, constructor

I have two constructors which feed values to readonly fields.

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample(string theIntAsString)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(theIntAsString);
        _intField = i;
    }

    public Sample(int theInt) => _intField = theInt;
    public int IntProperty    => _intField;

    private readonly int _intField;
}
```

One constructor receives the values directly, and the other does some calculation and obtains the values, then sets the fields.

Now here's the catch:

1. I don't want to duplicate the
   setting code. In this case, just one
   field is set but of course there may
   well be more than one.
2. To make the fields readonly, I need
   to set them from the constructor, so
   I can't "extract" the shared code to
   a utility function.
3. I don't know how to call one
   constructor from another.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2090, accepted):

Like this:

```
public Sample(string str) : this(int.Parse(str)) { }
```

Comment: @Avi: You can make a `static` method that manipulates the parameters.

Comment: May I know the execution order of this one? Everything in `Sample(string)` will be executed first then `Sample(int)` or the int version will be executed first then it will get back to the string version? (Like calling `super()` in Java?)

Comment: @RosdiKasim: The base class constructor always runs first.  You cannot use or see `this` until its base class has been initialized.

Comment: This has a limitation: the shared code is limited to one expression per constructor's argument. E.g. I can't check `str` for `null`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Yes, you can; use `?:` or call a static method.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, maybe you can do two constructors `public Sample(string str) : this(int.Parse(str))` and `public Sample() : this(0)`. It doesn't help if the user passes a `null` string as the argument, but it might be helpful in some cases.

Comment: @SLaks I flagged your first comment (regarding static) as obsolete but it was declined. Would you mind explaining what that comment refers to?

Comment: @Default: IIRC, he was asking how to run more logic on the ctor parameters before calling a different ctor.

Comment: @Slaks did you really mean to say "static" there though? A "private" method like "Init" would be appropriate, not a "static" method (how could that access local fields?)

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: Yes.  He wanted to run code (on the parameters) before calling the other ctor.  At that point, there is no instance.

Comment: Such code won't be able to write to any fields in the class, so what would be the purpose of it?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: To validate or transform the parameters.

Comment: I prefer to use an Init method in that case and call it from all constructors, or use a constructor that has all the parameters and others with less parameters call into it with default values for their own missing parameters. BTW, I see .NET gradually shifting away from the multiple-constructors paradigm that Java also used and going into patterns like new Point() { X=..., Y=... }. If I remember well X and Y in that case can also be properties, not just fields, so they can encapsulate their own validation logic if it is atomic (that is one doesn't need to validate the X,Y pair, but X&Y alone)

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: Actually, .Net is gradually moving away from that pattern, since it doesn't work with immutable types.

Answer (score 205):

If what you want can't be achieved satisfactorily without having the initialization in its own method (e.g. because you want to do too much before the initialization code, or wrap it in a try-finally, or whatever) you can have any or all constructors pass the readonly variables by reference to an initialization routine, which will then be able to manipulate them at will.

```
public class Sample
{
    private readonly int _intField;
    public int IntProperty => _intField; 

    private void setupStuff(ref int intField, int newValue) => intField = newValue;

    public Sample(string theIntAsString)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(theIntAsString);
        setupStuff(ref _intField,i);
    }

    public Sample(int theInt) => setupStuff(ref _intField, theInt);
}
```

Comment: +1 real solution. Using `base(...)` or `this(...)` we can only perform very limited operations.

Comment: How about using the `out` keyword instead of `ref`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: In this particular case it would likely be appropriate if the method only needed to store something there. On the other hand, the same approach could be used in cases where the caller would put something in the field and call a method that might or might not need to modify it; using `out` in the example might not make that clear. Also, I'm generally a bit skeptical of `out`, since there's no guarantee that an outside method with an `out` parameter will actually store anything there.

Comment: Why `ref`? Why not avoid that parameter at all and let the `setupStuff` method directly set the member variable?

Comment: @nawfal: Because it can't do so if the variable is `readonly`.

Comment: `setupStuff` can also return the `int` instead of it being passed in as a `ref` (or `out`) parameter.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter: If only one `readonly` field needs to be set, the code which sets it could call the method and assign the field using the return value, but any number of fields may be written directly with `ref`.  Also, in case it matters, changes made via the `ref` parameter take place immediately, even before the function returns, while those made using a function return value would not.

Comment: Alternative version, for situations where it makes sense to have one constructor call another: `public Sample(string theIntAsString) : this(int.Parse(theIntAsString)) {}` `public Sample(int theInt) { setupStuff(ref _intField, theInt); }`  Note that the first constructor, which calls another constructor, **does not** call `setupStuff`.

Comment: The solution is reasonable but it can be painful when the number of read-only fields increases ( you end up with a method with a lot of `ref`). Static methods that return calculated results and set the readonly to the return values can be an alternative.

Comment: @joe: One can minimize the number of `ref` arguments by using a readonly instance of a private structure type with public fields (not properties!).  Some people dislike such structures because they behave like a bunch of fields stuck together with duct tape rather than like objects, but what one needs is a a bunch of fields together with duct tape, using an exposed-field structure for that purpose (which *is* a bunch of duct-taped fields) makes a lot more sense than trying to make a structure do a bad imitation of an object doing a bad imitation of a joined bunch of fields.

Answer (score 79):

Before the body of the constructor, use either:

```
: base (parameters)

: this (parameters)
```

Example:

```
public class People: User
{
   public People (int EmpID) : base (EmpID)
   {
      // Add more statements here.
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work if I need some operations on arguments between constructors calls.

Comment: @Denis Can't you chain a constructor in the middle to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Denis you cannot do anything before you call a constructor. If you want to do something before initializing an object's properties, move initialization in a method other than the constructor example `init()`. You can call this method from any of your constructors.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib not when you need to call a parent constructor.

Answer (score 16):

I am improving upon supercat's answer. I guess the following can also be done:

```
class Sample
{
    private readonly int _intField;
    public int IntProperty
    {
        get { return _intField; }
    }

    void setupStuff(ref int intField, int newValue)
    {
        //Do some stuff here based upon the necessary initialized variables.
        intField = newValue;
    }

    public Sample(string theIntAsString, bool? doStuff = true)
    {
        //Initialization of some necessary variables.
        //==========================================
        int i = int.Parse(theIntAsString);
        // ................
        // .......................
        //==========================================

        if (!doStuff.HasValue || doStuff.Value == true)
           setupStuff(ref _intField,i);
    }

    public Sample(int theInt): this(theInt, false) //"false" param to avoid setupStuff() being called two times
    {
        setupStuff(ref _intField, theInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would possibly allow a third party to create a Sample without setting it up, by calling `new Sample(str, false)`.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: This is not good approach; confusing; unnecessarily complicated. If you call another constructor using `this`, then let that constructor call `setupStuff`; remove the call to setupStuff in the last constructor. Then you don't need the `doStuff` / `false` parameter.  (A lesser complaint is that if you do have a reason to use `doStuff` parameter, there is no benefit to making that a nullable Boolean `bool?`.  Just use `bool`.)  Also, what Teejay pointed out, means this is a fatally flawed design.

Comment: Better code might be:  `public Sample(string theIntAsString) : this(int.Parse(theIntAsString)) {}` `public Sample(int theInt) { setupStuff(ref _intField, theInt); }`  Note that the first constructor, which calls another constructor, **does not** call `setupStuff`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example that calls another constructor, then checks on the property it has set.

```
    public SomeClass(int i)
    {
        I = i;
    }

    public SomeClass(SomeOtherClass soc)
        : this(soc.J)
    {
        if (I==0)
        {
            I = DoSomethingHere();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is potentially much cleaner if you are using the default constructor fur some cases, and making small/specific changes for others.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, you can call other method before of the call base or this!

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(int number) : base(ConvertToString(number)) 
    {
    }

    private static string ConvertToString(int number) 
    { 
      return number.toString()
    }

}
```

Comment: Just for sake of overall answer - if your constructor should initialize any readonly fields, you can't use methods for this.

Answer (score 8):

**Constructor chaining** i.e you can use "Base" for Is a relationship and "This" you can use for same class, when you want call multiple Constructor in single call.

```
  class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass():this(10)
    {
    }
    public BaseClass(int val)
    {
    }
}
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new BaseClass();
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

When you inherit a class from a base class, you can invoke the base class constructor by instantiating the derived class

```
class sample
{
    public int x;

    public sample(int value)
    {
        x = value;
    }
}

class der : sample
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public der(int value1,int value2) : base(50)
    {
        a = value1;
        b = value2;
    }
}

class run 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        der obj = new der(10,20);

        System.Console.WriteLine(obj.x);
        System.Console.WriteLine(obj.a);
        System.Console.WriteLine(obj.b);
    }
}
```

Output of the [sample program](https://tio.run/##jY8xb8IwEIV3/4obY4lGSaQuWJ260qkDQ8VwNifkyjjI50AqxG9PnQRCiVSJW2y9e3ffO8Mvhk3XGYfMwLg/OBJnAakOjXbWgPURWiX@SqMt6ztHdA3JoTlO9dXC29hQg3QRFyFGwJYCLP/FoJor@hGcxu/UcjF9K5m2amTKXot5GLyFKdWk6ZtW3RPCNWJoPDxG44gxPcfabuEDrc84But3XxvAsOM5rz@x1t@J4Ok0JC6LRVXIgTS5Pn840j5/rz3XjvJ1sJFW1lOWRvNWqueM@KxRy@nQrvsF) is

> 50 10 20

---

You can also use `this` keyword to invoke a constructor from another constructor

```
class sample
{
    public int x;

    public sample(int value) 
    {
        x = value;
    }

    public sample(sample obj) : this(obj.x) 
    {
    }
}

class run
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        sample s = new sample(20);
        sample ss = new sample(s);

        System.Console.WriteLine(ss.x);
    }
}
```

The output of this [sample program](https://tio.run/##bY8xD4IwEIX3/oob6SAxjhInV50cHIxDqQ3WlJb0CmIMv70WComIt1xz773rdxxXHLn3XDFEQFZWSpA3gVBVnSvJQWoHbUa@R9GW9ErDVC0oDGqM9dXCLirZMOr@pWMDkz8obMHdJSbhnbazZR0J2chmaz0HQ8dcaI2RNzgyqRN0VuricgVmC1wwjf9hQNPiOVFs1jRbWH48SMfz@zq90Iky3RuNRon0bKUTB6mDCwP7dG/n/Qc) is

> 20

Answer (score 2):

Error handling and making your code reusable is key. I added string to int validation and it is possible to add other types if needed. Solving this problem with a more reusable solution could be this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample(object inputToInt)
    {
        _intField = objectToInt(inputToInt);
    }

    public int IntProperty => _intField;

    private readonly int _intField;
}

public static int objectToInt(object inputToInt)
{
    switch (inputToInt)
        {
            case int inputInt:
                return inputInt;
            break;
            case string inputString:
            if (!int.TryParse(inputString, out int parsedInt))
            {
                throw new InvalidParameterException($"The input {inputString} could not be parsed to int");
            }
            return parsedInt;

            default:
                throw new InvalidParameterException($"Constructor do not support {inputToInt.GetType().Name}");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Showing a different way to do it doesn't answer the question. And what if there are a dozen different fields and different ways of setting them? `objectToInt` won't help then.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a main constructor that used an OracleDataReader as an argument, but I wanted to use different query to create the instance:

I had this code:

```
public Subscriber(OracleDataReader contractReader)
    {
        this.contract = Convert.ToString(contractReader["contract"]);
        this.customerGroup = Convert.ToString(contractReader["customerGroup"]);
        this.subGroup = Convert.ToString(contractReader["customerSubGroup"]);
        this.pricingPlan= Convert.ToString(contractReader["pricingPlan"]);
        this.items = new Dictionary<string, Member>();
        this.status = 0;
        
        
    }
```

So I created the following constructor:

```
public Subscriber(string contract, string customerGroup) : this(getSubReader(contract, customerGroup))
    { }
```

and this method:

```
 private static  OracleDataReader getSubReader(string contract, string customerGroup)
    { 
        cmdSubscriber.Parameters[":contract"].Value = contract + "%";
        cmdSubscriber.Parameters[":customerGroup"].Value = customerGroup+ "%";
        return  cmdSubscriber.ExecuteReader();
        
    }
```

notes:  a statically defined cmdSubscriber is defined elsewhere in the code;  My main constructor has been simplified for this illustration.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.PrintFullName();

            Customer customer1 = new Customer("Zoyeb", "Shaikh");
            customer1.PrintFullName();
        }

    }

    public class Customer
    {
        string _firstName;
        string _lastName;

        public Customer(string fn, string ln)
        {
            _firstName = fn;
            _lastName = ln;
        }

        public Customer() : this("No-First Name","No-Last Name")
        {

        }
        public void PrintFullName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Full Name = {0}", this._firstName + " " + this._lastName);
        }
    }

}
```