# C# how to call a private constructor from a public one

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to be able to instaniate a class with a public constructor that will by default call a private constructor and I think it is something close to the code below, but it isn't.

```
    public MySQLConnector()
        : this MySQLConnector (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"])
    {
    }

    private MySQLConnector(string dbConnectionString)
    {
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Same way as [calling any other constructor of the same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009013/call-one-constructor-from-another) ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've almost got it. Just use `this(...)`, without the class name:

```
public MySQLConnector()
    : this(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"])
{
}
```

This is documented in [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx):

> A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the this keyword. Like **base**, **this** can be used with or without parameters, and any parameters in the constructor are available as parameters to **this**, or as part of an expression.