# C# - Call a constructor from another constructor after some calculations

Tags: c#, constructor

I have 2 constructors, accepting different types of arguments:

```
public someClass(String s) {

    // the string is parsed to an int array.
    int[] array = doSomething(s);

    this(array);
}

public someClass(int[] array) {
    doSomethingElse(array);
}
```

However on the first constructor I get "Method name is expected". Is there a way to have a constructor call another after performing other actions, or is it simply a limitation of C#?

Comment: Both constructors belongs to same `class`, how it makes difference doing same thing in other constructor? (Just curious)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as `doSomething` is static.

```
class someClass
{
    public someClass(String s)
        : this(doSomething(s))
    { }

    public someClass(int[] array)
    {
        doSomethingElse(array);
    }

    static int[] doSomething(string s)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. But  you could write

`public SomeClass(string s) : this(doSomething(s)){}`

which is perfectly fine, so long as `int[] doSomething(string)` is `static`.

Answer (score 2):

according to
[Call one constructor from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009013/call-one-constructor-from-another)

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(string s) : this(dosomething(s))
    {

    }

    public SomeClass(int[] something)
    {
    }


    private static int[] dosomething(string)
    {
        return new int[] { };
    }
}
```

i would use a static method to achieve what you want